# Differentiating $x^y=y^x$

Tags: calculus

The main question goes as:
Given:-
$x^y=y^x$
Find it's derivative.

I'm pretty much stuck at this question because I just can't figure out a step to proceed. I did some power altering which got me 
               $x^{y/x}=y$
Which is like a baby step, and gets me nowhere closer.

Please help me out. I am studying calculus merely as a tool which I use in physics, so I don't have a lot of in-depth knowledge. Just tell me how I can apply basics to solve this question.

Comment: I assume $y$ is a function of $x$ given *implicitly* by $x^y=y^x$, and you want to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

Comment: Do you know implicit differentiation

Comment: Uh no, I don't know implicit differentiation. I have a test tomorrow and I came across this question in my "Mathematics of Phyiscs" chapter booklet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying $\ln$ to both sides of the equation, we find
$$ y\ln x=x\ln y$$
Now differentiating both sides
$$ y'\ln x+yx^{-1}=\ln y+xy'y^{-1}.$$
Then
$$y'=\frac{y\ln  x-x}{x\ln y-y}=\frac{y\ln  x-x}{y\ln x-y}=1+\frac{y-x}{y(\ln x-1)}$$

Comment: Why only ln? Can't we apply log of any base?

Comment: You can do any base, but you generally choose ln if you have free choice.

Comment: Alright, I'm satisfied. Thanks everyone, and Hagen escpecially!